# NSView's print function in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa

I just moved my project to Xcode 10 (actually I put the files in a newly created project).

Now, in my NSView subclass, Xcode telle me that :

`public override func print(_ sender: Any?)`

does not override anything.
I guess the print() function has been renamed because it did conflict with the print() logging function.
Which name sould I use ?

Comment: I receive the same error in Xcode 9 as well, are you sure that function existed before? Even the documentation doesn't show it.

Comment: Thank you. It has indeed to be print. I did not look at the documentation. I used google instead and I must have poorly design my search words. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Swift 4/Xcode 9, the `NSView` method

```
- (void)print:(id)sender;
```

is imported to Swift as

```
func printView(_ sender: Any?)
```

so that it no longer conflicts with the global `print()` function.
This change is documented in the [AppKit Release Notes for macOS 10.13](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/index.html):

> print() methods in Swift
>
> NSWindow, NSView, NSDocument’s print() instance methods have been renamed to printWindow(), printView(), and printDocument() respectively in Swift 4. This fixes the unexpected experience where adding debug logging to a subclass of one of these instances shows a print panel instead.

(Found with the help of @hamishknight at [How does Swift translate -[NSView print] to printView()?](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-does-swift-translate-nsview-print-to-printview/13772)  in the Swift forum.)